# What's between central and peripheral?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I am looking for three adjectives that describe locations based on their centrality, that have clear order between them:

```
A > B > C
```

(i.e. A is more central than B is more central than C).

I have "central" and its antonym "peripheral". I am looking for a third adjective whose strength is between "central" and "peripheral", or more central than "central", or less central then "peripheral".

I hope the question is clear..

Comment: Semi-central, or semi-peripheral?

Comment: I thought about using semi- or sub-, but I prefer a single word if such exists.

Comment: How about *proximal* (meaning "near")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this fits the structure of the sentences you used as examples, but a word that has the meaning you are looking for is medial. A medial point would be a point roughly between the central and peripheral points.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed sounds similar to "central" and "peripheral".

Answer (score 1):

Three terms that I can come up with would be intermediate, intermediary, or transitional.

intermediate definition:

> coming between two things in time, place, order, character, etc

The term intermediary is often used to describe specifically a person that works between two others so this may not work in your context. It's definition when not describing people is closely linked to that of intermediate.

transistional definition (this is the definition for the noun transition but the word transitional is an adjective):

> movement, passage, or change from one position, state, stage, subject, concept, etc., to another; change